# Cannot get initial React Native App to Run

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Description

I can't get an initial React Native app to run, following a basic tutorial. The error seems to have to do with UIUserInterfaceIdiomCarPlay.

Reproduction Steps and Sample Code

Following the tutorial here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.23/docs/tutorial.html#content

I created a new React Native project `react-native init AwesomeProject`
Then went into the directory, and ran `react-native run-ios`

Note I also tried from Xcode, and the myriad fixes online, but still no dice. This is the error I got:

`/Users/lauracressman/Desktop/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/React/Base/RCTPlatform.m:26:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'UIUserInterfaceIdiomCarPlay'; did you mean 'UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad'?
    case UIUserInterfaceIdiomCarPlay:
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad
In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/lauracressman/Desktop/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/React/Base/RCTPlatform.m:12:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIDevice.h:33:5: note: 'UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad' declared here
    UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_2), // iPad style UI
    ^
/Users/lauracressman/Desktop/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/React/Base/RCTPlatform.m:26:10: error: duplicate case value 'UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad'
    case UIUserInterfaceIdiomCarPlay:
         ^
/Users/lauracressman/Desktop/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/React/Base/RCTPlatform.m:22:10: note: previous case defined here
    case UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad:
         ^
2 errors generated.`

Additional Information

React Native version: 0.42.3

Platform: iOS

Development Operating System: MacOS

Dev tools: Xcode, command line

Comment: What version of Xcode are you running?

Comment: Update Xcode to version 8.1 or above

Answer (score 0):

[Someone](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11265#issuecomment-264640415) was recently facing the same problem with that error message `Use of undeclared identifier 'UIUserInterfaceIdiomCarPlay'; did you mean 'UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad'?`. He commented out lines 26 & 27 from `node_modules/react-native/React/Base/RCTPlatform.m` and apparently got it to work. It might be related to using an outdated version of Xcode